# Table with expanded rows

Tags: angular, html-table

I am trying to create a table like the following:
[image]

For this I have followed several examples on the internet.

I have achieved the following:

```
<table>
    <tr width="35">
      <th>Columna A</th>
      <th>Columna B</th>
      <th>Columna C</th>
      <th>Columna D</th>
      <th>Columna E</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let result of Array">
      <td [attr.rowspan]="result.totalOfAnswers">{{result.infoA}}</td>
      <td [attr.rowspan]="result.totalOfAnswers">{{result.infoB}}</td>
      <td [attr.rowspan]="result.totalOfAnswers">{{result.infoC}} </td>
      <td [attr.rowspan]="result.totalOfAnswers">{{result.infoD}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let answer of result.userAnswers">{{answer}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The variable `totalOfAnswers` contains`userAnswers.length` defined in the `ts`

With this code I get the following:

[image]

I know I have to add another `tr` to iterate the second `ngFor`, but if I do this, I lose the value of `result.answer` (iterated in the first`tr`) since I must close the first `tr` .

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your requirement in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fe1nvv). I didn't run into the necessity of closing the existing `tr`.

Let me know if I missed something. I did it 2 ways, just to see the various options.

---

Update: Added in a way to format null responses.

Comment: Wow! You made it so easy! You don't even need the `rowspan` attribute. ¿Can I ask you for one little detail more? If i.e. userAnswer[1] is null, print something like "Not answered" to the user.